# How to detect standard language constructions, like negations or questions?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

There are some words, phrases and language constructions which should be available without any additional training or definition. At least, I was expecting to have that from NLP.

For example:

How to detect negations?
- no, I don't need gift card
- no gift card
- gift card is not required

How to detect that the sentence is question and what type?
- How many colors do you have?
- When will you call me?

Do I need to cover all that with my custom entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Google "CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API" - https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/ . It has all I imagined that kind of service should have.

You can try it on above link in "Try the API" textarea an you'll see. It gives you even relation between words, their role, tense ... just great!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything specialized for this. A mixture of [comma-resolution](http://svivek.com/research/publications/SRSRR08.pdf) and sentiment analysis might give you sth.